# How to add more tables in a SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am facing problem in creating more than two tables in SQLite database in android.
I want to add two more table in my App's SQLite database. 
When I try to add more tables, it shows an error **Unexpected token.**

This is my Database.class

```
public class DBForms {
public static final int FORMS = 0 ;
public static final int ADMITCARDS = 1;

private FormHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public DBForms (Context context){
    mHelper = new FormHelper(context);
    mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void insertForms(int table, ArrayList<FormItem> listForms,boolean clearPrevious){
    if (clearPrevious){
        deleteForms(table);
    }


    //create a sql prepared statement
    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + (table == FORMS ? FormHelper.TABLE_FORMS : FormHelper.TABLE_ADMITCARDS) + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
    //compile the statement and start a transaction
    SQLiteStatement statement = mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
    mDatabase.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < listForms.size(); i++){
        FormItem currentForm = listForms.get(i);
        statement.clearBindings();
        //for a given column index, simply bind the data to be put inside that index
        statement.bindString(2,currentForm.getTitle());
        statement.bindLong(3,currentForm.getLastdate() == null ? -1 : currentForm.getLastdate().getTime());
        statement.bindString(4,currentForm.getCategory());
        statement.bindString(5,currentForm.getDetails());
        statement.bindString(6,currentForm.getProfilePic());
        statement.bindString(7,currentForm.getUrl());

        statement.execute();

    }
    //set the transaction as successful and end the transaction
    L.m("inserting entries " + listForms.size() + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    mDatabase.endTransaction();
}
public ArrayList<FormItem> readForms(int table){
    ArrayList<FormItem> listForms = new ArrayList<>();

        //get a list of columns to be retrieved, we need all of them
    String[] columns = {FormHelper.COLUMN_UID,
            FormHelper.COLUMN_TITLE,
            FormHelper.COLUMN_LASTDATE,
            FormHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY,
            FormHelper.COLUMN_DETAILS,
            FormHelper.COLUMN_PROFILEPIC,
            FormHelper.COLUMN_URL,
    };
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query((table == FORMS ? FormHelper.TABLE_FORMS : FormHelper.TABLE_ADMITCARDS), columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        L.m("loading entries " + cursor.getCount() + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        do {
            FormItem formItem = new FormItem();

            formItem.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormHelper.COLUMN_TITLE)));
            long lastdateMilliseconds = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormHelper.COLUMN_LASTDATE));
            formItem.setLastdate(lastdateMilliseconds != -1 ? new Date(lastdateMilliseconds): null);
            formItem.setCategory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY)));
            formItem.setDetails(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormHelper.COLUMN_DETAILS)));
            formItem.setProfilePic(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormHelper.COLUMN_PROFILEPIC)));
            formItem.setUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormHelper.COLUMN_URL)));

            listForms.add(formItem);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return listForms;
}

public  void  deleteForms(int table){
    mDatabase.delete((table == FORMS ? FormHelper.TABLE_FORMS : FormHelper.TABLE_ADMITCARDS), null, null);

}
private static class FormHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_ADMITCARDS = "admitcards";
    public static final String TABLE_FORMS = "forms";
    public static final String COLUMN_UID ="id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE ="title";
    public static final String COLUMN_LASTDATE ="lastdate";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY ="category";
    public static final String COLUMN_DETAILS ="details";
    public static final String COLUMN_PROFILEPIC ="profilePic";
    public static final String COLUMN_URL ="url";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FORM = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_FORMS + " (" +
            COLUMN_UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_LASTDATE + " INTEGER," +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_DETAILS + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_PROFILEPIC+ " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_URL+ " TEXT" +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ADMITCARDS = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_ADMITCARDS + " (" +
            COLUMN_UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_LASTDATE + " INTEGER," +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_DETAILS + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_PROFILEPIC+ " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_URL+ " TEXT" +
            ");";


    private static final String DB_NAME = "forms_db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private Context mContext;


    public FormHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FORM);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ADMITCARDS);

            L.m("create table forms executed");
        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
            L.t(mContext, exception + "");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
           L.m("upgrade table form executed");
            db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE " + TABLE_FORMS + " IF EXISTS;");
            db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE " + TABLE_ADMITCARDS + " IF EXISTS;");

            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
            L.t(mContext, exception + "SQLiteException");
        }

     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Show code for other two tables

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE " + TABLE_FORMS + " IF EXISTS;");
```

This is not the [correct syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html); the `IF EXISTS` must come before the table name.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing multiple table in my code so I did it like this and it worked for me.Maybe it works for you too.

```
public class DB_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DBNAME="users.db";
public DB_Helper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table users(username TEXT primary key,password TEXT,admin TEXT)");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table station(station_name TEXT primary key,latitude REAL,longitude REAL)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists users");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists station");
}
public Boolean insertData(String username,String password,String admin){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("username",username);
    values.put("password",password);
    values.put("admin",admin);

    long result=db.insert("users",null,values);
    if (result==-1)
        return  false;
    else
        return true;

}
public Boolean insert_station_Data(String station_name,float latitude,float longitude){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("station_name",station_name);
    values.put("latitude",latitude);
    values.put("longitude",longitude);
    long result=db.insert("station",null,values);
    if (result==-1)
        return  false;
    else
        return true;
}
public Boolean checkusername(String username){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from users where username=?",new String[]{username});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public Boolean checkusernamepassword(String username,String password,String admin){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from users where username=? and password=? and admin=?",new String[]{username,password,admin});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

I have users table and bus station table and also some methods for both tables.Once I had only users table and I wanted to add station table but with this code I couldn't add it firstly.I deleted my database and rerun the code (Created both table same time) they both has created and methods are also working.So you may try that too maybe.

Answer (score -1):

You should increase the database version value to 2.

```
private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
```